# Time series data prediction with multiple n numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

I am studying time series data.

If you look at the time series data you have run with the examples so far, they all have similarly only two columns. One is a date, and one is any value.

For example, in the case of a stock price increase forecast, we predict a 'single' stock.

If so, can you predict multiple stocks simultaneously in time series data analysis?

For example, after the subjects had taken medicines that affected their liver levels, they got liver count data by date so far. Based on this, I would like to experiment with predicting at which point the liver level rises or falls in the future. At this time, I need to predict several patients at the same time, not one patient. How do I specify the data set in this case?

Is it possible to label by adding one column? Or am I not really understanding the nature of time series data analysis?

If anyone knows anything related, I would be really grateful if you can advise me or give me a reference site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the predictions for each patient separately. You probably don't want the prediction on one of the patient to vary because of what happens to the others at the same time.

Machine Learning is not just about giving data to a model and getting back results, you also have to think the model, what should be its input and output here. For time series, you would probably give as input what was observed on a patient in the previous days, and try to predict what will happen in the next one. For one patient, you do not need the data of the others patients, and if you give it to your model, it will try to use it and capture some noise from the training data, which is not what you want.

However as you could expect similar behaviors in each patient, you can build a model for all the patients, and not one model for each patient. The typical input would be of the form :

[X(t - k, i), X(t - k + 1, i), ..., X(t - 1, i)]

where X(t, i) is the observation at time t for the patient i, to predict X(t, i). Train your model with the data of all the patients.

As you give a medical example, know that if you have some covariates like the weight or the gender of the patients you can include them in your model to capture their individual characteristics. In this case the input of the model to predict X(t, i) would be :

[X(t - k, i), X(t - k + 1, i), ..., X(t - 1, i), C1(i), ..., Cp(i)]

where C1(i)...Cp(i) are the covariates of the patient. If you do not have theses covariates, it is not a problem, they can just improve the results in some cases. Note that all covariates are not necessarily useful.

Comment: thank you for the answer!

Is that what I understand?
1. In the model of time series data, it is not possible to train the model at once by labeling the patient's data set.
2.Therefore, each patient should be trained with each dataset and see the result.

Comment: Not exactly. You can train the model at once, however in one 'observation' you only give the data of one patient.